# All Monitors stopped working after update to 23.04

Tags: nvidia, graphics, 23.04

I upgraded to 23.04 today and everything worked fine for about 3 or 4 hours on my HP Pavillon laptop. It has a Nvidia gtx graphics card.

After around 3 to 4 hours suddenly my laptop screen went black (not dimm or dark but OFF) and my external monitor went black with a notification that "no HDMI connection detected" so i guess all graphics outputs just stopped.

My Laptop is less than 2 years old.

The laptop still turns on and the fans work and the keyboard lights too. Just the screen doesn't work.

Does anyone know how to fix this while I have no possibly whatsoever to see anything on the screen? Even BIOS won't show.

Comment: *"Even BIOS won't show."* - Are you sure about this? Do you mean you can't get to the BIOS menu, or are you saying the display isn't working at all? Are you sure you didn't use a key combination on your laptop that turns off the screen or sets the backlight to 0? If your screen isn't working even before the OS loads, then unfortunately it doesn't have anything to do with the OS.

Comment: No I'm sure that I didn't use any key combo and that my screen backlight is normal because as soon as this happened I saw on my external monitor the message "hdmi cable not detected" and even the external went black. So you think it's not OS related and HP has messed up again?

Comment: If you have no screen before the OS loads then it has nothing to do with the OS. Nothing in Ubuntu has any jurisdiction over what is happening with your BIOS because nothing in Ubuntu has loaded and Ubuntu cannot override your motherboard firmware.